# How to formulate SQL Distinct-Statement where there are more that one point per condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want a SQL Select statement that does this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column1,Column2,..,ColumnN FROM TABLE
WHERE whereStatement AND Entries.Count>1
```

So I want only the Column1 to ColumnN IF there where multiple entries that fullfill the WHERE conditions. The back ground of this is that I want to access curves and something with one point is not a curve. It has at least have to have two points in order to constitute the property curve.

**Question: How does one filter for number of entries with a given WHERE condition?**

So here is my current strategy:

**1 The user selects Materials and a Curve Type**

**2 The query above is run in order to show the accessible data (here state and material)**

Example: For the final data below there would be 4 entries (material1 dry) (material1 conditioned) (material2 dry) (material2 conditioned)

**3 In a next step the user can select the conditiones (material state combination) he wants to see as a curve**

**4 A query is formulated using the selected conditions above**

Now the issue is the following: As seen in this query result, material1 has only one entry for 23°C this is not a curve.

[image]

A bit background if useful:

I have a oracle material database with a interface for VBA excel. I formulate queries using VBA code. For example is one plot that I get using these queries Modulus vs Temperature. There one or multiple modulus can be stored and if only one is stored this one should not be shown as Temperature vs Modulus.

Comment: Please share sample data and desired results. It's not clear what you are trying to do here and that will help immensely.

Comment: @JNevill I try to clarify the question in order to make it as understandably as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, I think a `HAVING` clause with `GROUP BY` does what you want:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, ..., ColumnN
FROM TABLE
WHERE <where conditions>
GROUP BY Column1, Column2, ..., ColumnN
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```